# Dynamically created controls in Page_Load()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question regarding creating controls in runtime in ASP.NET 4.0. I'm building a application and in admin.aspx page I have multiple controls (DropDownLists) which are dynamically created with values from a Sql database. I know that for having events fired for dynamically created controls, I have to create this controls in Page_Load() or in Page_Init().

My project has a Master Page, in which I have a 1 second timer which updates a clock. This timer event calls my admin.aspx Page_Load() function, so my method which creates dynamic controls it's called every 1 second - connection to database is made every one second, please look below to my code.

It's a good practice to do that? Can you please propose some ideas?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _SinopticBackgroundColor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SinopticBackgroundColor"];
    panelContent.Style.Add("background-color", _SinopticBackgroundColor);

    Control c = GetControlThatCausedPostBack(this);
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (c.ID.Equals("btnManageCategory"))
            hfPageManage.Value = "category";
        else if (c.ID.Equals("btnManageDevices"))
            hfPageManage.Value = "device";
    }

    if (hfPageManage.Value.Equals("category"))
    {
        cbTreeViewGroup.Visible = false;
        UpdateSinopticCategoryManager(TreeView1.SelectedNode); //this is the functions which loads controls from database..
    }
    else if (hfPageManage.Value.Equals("device"))
    {
        cbTreeViewGroup.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cbTreeViewGroup.Visible = false;
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadFunctions(); // loads some values from database into datatables
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

And here is the functions which creates controls

```
private void UpdateSinopticCategoryManager(TreeNode node = null)
{
    if (node == null)
        return;

    DataTable categoriiDT = null;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID";
            command.Parameters.Add("CategoryID", node.Value);
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("CATEGORYPROPERTIES");
            connection.Open();
            ad.Fill(ds);
            // verificam sa avem date 
            if (ds.Tables.Count <= 0)
                return;
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0)
                return;
            categoriiDT = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }

    // generate table
    Table table = new Table();
    table.Style.Add("position", "relative");
    table.Style.Add("top", "20px");
    table.Style.Add("margin-left", "20px");
    table.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
    table.BorderWidth = 1;
    // header
    TableHeaderRow hr = new TableHeaderRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        TableHeaderCell hc = new TableHeaderCell();
        if (i > 0)
        {
            hc.Text = "FUNCTION";
            //hc.Width = 200;
        }
        else
        {
            hc.Width = 100;
        }
        hr.Cells.Add(hc);
    }
    table.Rows.Add(hr);

    var inputs = (from a in categoriiDT.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                 where a.ColumnName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("input")
                 select a.ColumnName).ToArray();
    if (inputs.Count() <= 0)
        return;

    //rows input
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Count(); i++)
    {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            if (j > 0)
            {
                // adaugare 2 dropdownlist

                DropDownList categList = new DropDownList();
                categList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(categList_SelectedIndexChanged);

                foreach (DataRow row in functionsCategories.Rows)
                {
                    categList.Items.Add(new ListItem(row["FunctionCategoryName"].ToString(), row["FunctionCategoryID"].ToString()));
                }

                DropDownList funcList = new DropDownList();
                int selF = 0, selC = 0;
                for (int fi = 0; fi < functions.Rows.Count; fi++)// (DataRow row in functions.Rows)
                {
                    funcList.Items.Add(new ListItem(functions.Rows[fi]["FunctionName"].ToString(), functions.Rows[fi]["FunctionID"].ToString()));
                    if (functions.Rows[fi]["FunctionID"].ToString() == categoriiDT.Rows[0][inputs[i]].ToString())
                    {
                        selF = fi;
                        selC = Int32.Parse(functions.Rows[fi]["FunctionCategoryID"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                funcList.SelectedIndex = selF;
                categList.SelectedIndex = functionsCategories.Rows.IndexOf(
                    (from c in functionsCategories.AsEnumerable()
                    where c["FunctionCategoryID"].ToString().Equals(selC.ToString())
                    select c).FirstOrDefault());

                cell.Controls.Add(categList);
                cell.Controls.Add(funcList);
            }
            else
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = "INPUT " + i.ToString();
                label.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                cell.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            tableRow.Cells.Add(cell);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
    }

    //rows output
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            if (j > 0)
            {
                DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
                list.Width = 200;
                list.Items.AddRange(GetOutputFunctions());
                list.BorderColor = Color.Goldenrod;
                cell.Controls.Add(list);
            }
            else
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = "OUTPUT " + i.ToString();
                label.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
                cell.Controls.Add(label);
             }
             row.Cells.Add(cell);
         }
         table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    // add table to panel
    panelContent.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

It's about this: DropDownList categList = new DropDownList();

Comment: Have you ever used an `UpdatePanel`? I'm not entirely clear on what this code does exactly, but if you only need to update part of the page, you can resend just parts of the page without resending all of it. I'd also rethink doing this every second. That's an awful fast refresh rate. You'll need to be sure that the underlying SQL query is as efficient as possible or you'll end up with your DBA screaming at you about how hard you're hitting the database.

Comment: panelContent is an asp:UpdatePanel. Anyway, I've changed my structure now. Thank you!